# How can you tell what process has a URL registered with HTTP.SYS

Tags: windows, http.sys

I have a program that is trying to register a URL with HTTP.SYS. It is giving the error "HTTP could not register URL http://+:1234/PathName/. Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS."

How can I find out what the other application is? Is there a command line I could run that would list all the registered URLs and the process ID that has them registered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `netsh http show servicestate`, it will show you a list of Server Session with the URL they registered:

[image: Server session view]

Remember the "Request queue name" and scroll toward the end of the command output to find the "Request queue" with the same "Request queue name", and you'll see the PID of the controller process:

[image: Request queues]

Comment: So near and yet so far. I've just tried that but the request queue is named "Request queue is unnamed." There are multiple unnamed request queues listed at the bottom.

Comment: It seems if I add the `view=requestq` parameter it ties the session and queue output together so you can see which session is attached to which queue even if they are not named.